# How to create a temporary function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

I have to execute a loop in database. This is only a one time requirement.
After executing the function, I am dropping the function now.

Is there any good approach for creating temporary / disposable functions?

Answer (score 174):

I needed to know how to do a many time use in a script I was writing.  Turns out you can create a temporary function using the pg_temp schema.  This is a schema that is created on demand for your connection and is where temporary tables are stored.  When your connection is closed or expires this schema is dropped.  Turns out if you create a function on this schema, the schema will be created automatically.  Therefore,

```
create function pg_temp.testfunc() returns text as 
$$ select 'hello'::text $$ language sql;
```

will be a function that will stick around as long as your connection sticks around.  No need to call a drop command.

Answer (score 90):

A couple of **additional notes** to the [smart trick in @crowmagnumb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9981540/939860):

- The function must be **schema-qualified** at all times, even if `pg_temp` is in the `search_path` (like it is by default), [according to Tom Lane](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/15191.1208975632@sss.pgh.pa.us) to prevent Trojan horses:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pg_temp.f_inc(int)
  RETURNS int AS 'SELECT $1 + 1' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

SELECT pg_temp.f_inc(42);
f_inc
-----
43
```

- A function created in the temporary schema is only visible inside the **same session** (just like temp tables). It's invisible to all other sessions (even for the same role). You *can* access the function as a different role in the same session after `SET ROLE`.
- Works for a [`PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) in similar fashion.

  - [When to use stored procedure / user-defined function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118419/3684)
- You could even create a functional index based on this "temp" function:

  ```
    CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON tbl (pg_temp.f_inc(id));
  ```

Thereby creating a plain index using a temporary function on a non-temp table. Such an index would be visible to all sessions but still only valid for the creating session. The query planner will not use a functional index, where the expression is not repeated in the query. Still a bit of a dirty trick. It will be dropped automatically when the session is closed - as a depending object. Feels like this should not be allowed at all ...

---

If you just need to execute a function repeatedly and all you need is SQL, consider a [**prepared statement**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) instead. It acts much like a *temporary SQL function* that dies at the end of the session. Not the *same* thing, though, and can only be used by itself with `EXECUTE`, not nested inside another query. Example:

```
PREPARE upd_tbl AS
UPDATE tbl t SET set_name = $2 WHERE tbl_id = $1;
```

Call:

```
EXECUTE upd_tbl(123, 'foo_name');
```

Details:

- [Split given string and prepare case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018991/split-given-string-and-prepare-case-statement/28220532#28220532)

Answer (score 32):

If you are using version 9.0, you can do this with the new DO statement:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html

With previous versions, you'll need to create the function, call it, and drop it again.

Comment: ... It is useful for scripting on terminal, but you can not call it again, like an "anonimous function" (or lambda), so DO statment is not so useful as a "temporary function".

Comment: @PeterKrauss: if you want to call it again, you need to create a real function.

Comment: Of course my a_hourse :-) I was only showing the theoretical path for implement "temporary"...  This is why the better answer  (possible with PostgreSQL), for the main question, is `pg_temp.foo()`. I not understand why (!?) today, 2014, with so simple and so fast examples as [Lua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)), [SQL DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language) languages can not offer [lambda functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) (!).

Comment: Also, `DO` statements can't have input parameters and can't return a result, contrary to functions.

Comment: If it doesn't return, should we call it a "function"?

Comment: My understanding is that the `DO ... $$ ... $$ LANGUAGE ...;` is only useful for its side-effects (the return value is discarded). It's not a function, used in the context of a lambda function in functional programming languages

Answer (score -7):

For ad hock procedures, [cursors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/plpgsql-cursors.html) aren't too bad. They are too inefficient for productino use however.

They will let you easily loop on sql results in the db.

Comment: Why do you think cursors are inefficient in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Cursors hold up a database connection when loop. A web page with hundreds of long running cursors will starve connections and bring the site/database to its knees.