# Return value from anonymous function postgresql

Tags: postgresql, anonymous-function, plpgsql

How to?

For easy example. I have a simple function:

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$ DECLARE
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'SELECT NOW()';
END $$;
```

How I can return value of "NOW()" or other values from also anonymous function? The function is given as an example I have a more complex function.

Answer (score 18):

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$ DECLARE
BEGIN
execute '
create temporary table t
as
SELECT NOW()
';
END $$;

select * from t;
```

Comment: oh... That I need to insert or select (if insert down because pkey is duplicate).

Comment: @Arturgspb Could you edit your question with the meaning of the above comment as I don't understand it?

Comment: How to use same block if this is used in CFQuery block with coldfusion??

Comment: Oh that's genius! Finally a workaround. Postgres will be slightly less odious now.

Answer (score 15):

It is not an anonymous function, but rather [anonymous code block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html).

- if you need to *return* values, consider [creating real functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html);
- if you need to output some debug info, just [`RAISE NOTICE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html).

Comment: I asked specifically about the anonymous functions

Comment: There're no anonymous functions as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Arturgspb: ["The code block is ... returning `void`."](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) Note the "returning `void`".

Comment: If you are worried about creating a function in a live database, consider creating a temp function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990622