# Line breaks in psql query file possible?

Tags: bash, psql

I'm running a bash file to handle some psql tasks. However, I'd like the text file containing the query (fp_query.txt) to accept line breaks for enhanced readability. Currently, I'm getting this error:

```
parse error at end of line
```

when I maintain line breaks. Is there some way to have the interpreter ignore line breaks so that I can keep them in the query file?

For reference, here's the .sh file:

```
export PGPASSFILE=.pgpass
psql -h [hostname] -d [dbname] -U [user] -f fp_query.txt
```

And here's fp_query.txt:

```
\copy (SELECT created_at::date, COUNT(*)
    FROM ela_snapshots 
    WHERE created_at::date > CURRENT_DATE - 30 
    GROUP BY 1) to 'ELA_comp_tot_daily_sess.csv' with CSV HEADER
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not that you have line-breaks in your query file, but that you have line-breaks inside the `\copy` meta-command. According to [the "Meta-Commands" section of the `psql` documentation for PostgreSQL 9.5](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS):

> **Parsing for arguments stops at the end of the line**, or when another unquoted backslash is found. An unquoted backslash is taken as the beginning of a new meta-command. The special sequence `\\` (two backslashes) marks the end of arguments and continues parsing SQL commands, if any. That way SQL and psql commands can be freely mixed on a line. But in any case, **the arguments of a meta-command cannot continue beyond the end of the line**.

(emphasis mine). This would be equally true if you were running this at the interactive `psql` prompt.

One workaround might be to [create a temporary function consisting of your query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4990622/978917), and having your `\copy` meta-command run a query that just calls that function.

Answer (score 4):

## Direct answer and solution

As noted in [ruakh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34891947/7508588), PostgreSQL meta-commands must occupy a single line. I work around this by creating a temporary table for `\copy` to process.

A quick transformation of your file, `fp_query.txt`, would look like this.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE "temp_unique_name" AS
    SELECT created_at::date, COUNT(*)
    FROM ela_snapshots 
    WHERE created_at::date > CURRENT_DATE - 30 
    GROUP BY 1;
\copy "temp_uniq_name" to 'ELA_comp_tot_daily_sess.csv' with CSV HEADER
```

There are other improvements you might consider.

## Additional discussion

### Randomized name for temporary table

It's not likely you'll run into table-name collisions but, just the same, avoiding them is quite simple by creating a random name...

```
SELECT 'tmp_' || (RANDOM()*1e15)::INT8 AS table_name
\gset
```

... and using the name like this.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE ":table_name" AS
   [...query...]
\copy ":table_name" to 'ELA_comp_tot_daily_sess.csv' with CSV HEADER
```

Note the following about the psql features used here.

- The `\gset` meta-command runs the query in the buffer and sets non-null values as variables named like the column aliases. For more information, look for `\gset` [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS). **Importantly**, note that the query does **not** end with a semicolon, as this would immediately execute the buffer!
- Like all `psql` variables, the variables created by `\gset` are used by pre-pending a colon to the variable name, like `:table_name`.
- The value of `RANDOM()...` should be `CAST`/converted to an `INT` in order to eliminate any decimal point, which would be troublesome in an unquoted table name and possibly confusing even when quoted. Here, I use a `BIGINT` (or the alias `INT8`) because of the large factor I'm multiplying by.

All that said, it's unlikely you are creating enough temporary tables to create conflicting names.

### Dynamic filename for output

As long as you're using `\gset` to create a table-name, you might consider creating a dynamic filename for output.

```
SELECT 'tmp_' || (RANDOM()*1e15)::INT8 AS table_name,
       'ELA_comp_tot_' || to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS') || '.csv' AS file_name
\gset
```

Now, you can use the following.

```
\copy ":table_name" to ":file_name" with CSV HEADER
```

As written, this would output to something like `ELA_comp_tot_20180404_142329.csv`. The `.csv` extension doesn't alter the output, by the way, but better indicates the file contents, particularly to GUI based filesystem interfaces.

### Syntax of `\copy` meta-command

Your sample code (which I've copied verbatim to avoid confusion), is using a `COPY` command syntax from prior to version 9.0, as mentioned [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html#AEN69825). Using the newer syntax, it would look like this:

```
\COPY ":table_name" TO ":file_name" WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE)
```

This is a minor point, as the syntax is still officially supported through version 9.x. It also doesn't matter that I like to capitalize `KEYWORDS`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to convert newline to space before passing it to psql:

```
cat fp_query.txt | tr -s '\n' ' ' | psql -h [hostname] -d [dbname] -U [user]
```