# In pgplsql create function within scope of anonymous block

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

In plsql, we can create  function/procedure within an anonymous block and reuse it.

example:

```
declare
   procedure TEST_DATE
   as
   begin
     dbms_output.put_line (sysdate);
   end;
begin
   TEST_DATE;
end;
```

could we do similar  in pgplsql ?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: Is there any way to re-use anonymous block or should i create a function and later drop it?

Comment: You can create a temporary function: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4990622/330315

Comment: if you want just `dbms_output.put_line`, you can create function in transaction, reuse it as many times as you need and rollback - it will "drop" function