# Postgresql : with clause function

Tags: postgresql, function, with-clause

does PostgreSQL support function in with Clause?
oracle has the functionality as below

```
WITH
  function add_fnc(p_id number) return number
  is
  begin
    return p_id + 1; 
  end;
select add_fnc(id1) from test_tbl;
```

Comment: The short answer: No. See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as CTE functions in [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) (as cofemann noted), but it seems what you are looking for are temporary functions. Take a look [How to create a temporary function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990622/how-to-create-a-temporary-function-in-postgresql)