# Can PostgreSQL declare a procedure inside a procedure?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, ddl

```
create or replace procedure procedure_1()
language plpgsql
as $$ 
declare 
    precedure procedure_2()
    begin 
        select 1;
    end
begin
    select 1;
end; $$
```

Is there any way to declare a `procedure_2()` inside `procedure_1()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** - if by "declare" you mean "create".

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure_1(INOUT result int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc1$
BEGIN
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure_2(INOUT result int)
     LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
   $proc2$
   BEGIN
      result := 2;
   END
   $proc2$;
   
   result := 1;
END
$proc1$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=604e9973bbac270f373f9f4ae843cebf)*

You just have to get the quoting right. See:

- [What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql/12172353#12172353)
- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Functions and procedures are not "declared", but ["created"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) in Postgres. That creates an object in the database which is then visible and usable by all with appropriate permissions. (Not just a temporary object local to the procedure or transaction.)

You can, however, create a "temporary" function or procedure, with this "hack" - if that's what you had in mind:

- [How to create a temporary function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990622/how-to-create-a-temporary-function-in-postgresql)